# i have a problem with the importation of sql

Tags: python, sql, import, backend, pls

i have a problem with the importation of sql

```py
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
with open('crea_posts.sql') as f:
    connection.executescript(f.read())
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

debug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tamarrino\Desktop\flask app\init_db.py", line 4, in <module>
    connection.executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.OperationalError: 1 values for 2 columns
```

this is the `crea_post.sql`

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

CREATE TABLE posts (
    titolo TEXT,
    info TEXT
);

INSERT INTO posts (titolo, info) VALUES (
    'Lava la macchina',
    'Lava accuratamente la carrozzeria e gli interni'
);
INSERT INTO posts (titolo, info) VALUES (
    'Lava il frigo'
);
INSERT INTO posts (titolo, info) VALUES (
    'Porta la macchina dal meccanico'
    'Guasto al motore'
);
```

Comment: can you share the sql query also? have you tried running the query inside `crea_posts.sql` manually? Does it run successfully?

Comment: to me this is arabic. Can you give me step by step instructions?

Comment: this is crea_posts.sql

Comment: this is the debug       Import "flask" could not be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a comma in the last values of the insert. It should be

```
INSERT INTO posts (titolo, info) VALUES ( 'Porta la macchina dal meccanico', 'Guasto al motore' );
```

Comment: this is the debug Import "flask" could not be resolved

Comment: try adding `import flask` at the top of your script.
If you still get an error, check if flask is installed or not. You can run `pip install flask` in the command prompt window.

Comment: ok thanks,  it works you are my hero